# Python Splinter clicking button CSS

Tags: python, selenium, splinter

I'm having trouble selecting a button in my Splinter script using the `find_by_css` method. The documentation is sparse at best, and I haven't found a lot of good articles out there with examples.

```
br.find_by_css('div#edit-field-download-files-und-0 a.button.launcher').first.click()
```

...where `br` is my browser instance.

I've tried a few different ways of writing it.  I'm really not sure how I'm supposed to do it because the documentation doesn't give any hard examples of the syntax.

Here's a screenshot of the element.

[image: Here's a screenshot of the element I'm trying to manipulate]

Sorry the screenshot kind of sucks.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 3):

The css selector looks alright, just that i am not sure from where have you got `find_by_css` as a method?

How about this :-

```
br.find_element_by_css_selector("div#edit-field-download-files-und-0 a.button.launcher").click()
```

Selenium provides the following methods to locate elements in a page:

```
find_element_by_id
find_element_by_name
find_element_by_xpath
find_element_by_link_text
find_element_by_partial_link_text
find_element_by_tag_name
find_element_by_class_name
find_element_by_css_selector
```

To find multiple elements (these methods will return a list):

```
find_elements_by_name
find_elements_by_xpath
find_elements_by_link_text
find_elements_by_partial_link_text
find_elements_by_tag_name
find_elements_by_class_name
find_elements_by_css_selector
```

Comment: `find_by_css` is a method within the Splinter library, which appears to be being used in conjunction with Selenium.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on something similar where I'm trying to click stuff on a webpage. The documentation for [find_by_css()](https://splinter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/driver-and-element-api.html?highlight=find_by_css#splinter.driver.DriverAPI.find_by_css) is very poor and you need to type the css path to the element you want to click.
[image: Say we want to click the about page on python.org]
Say we want to go to the about tab on python.org

```
from splinter import Browser
from time import sleep
with Browser() as browser: #<--Create browser instance (firefox default driver)
    browser.visit('http://www.python.org') #<--Visits url string
    browser.find_by_css('#about > a').click()
    #                       ^--Put css path here in quotes
    sleep(5)
```

If your connection is good you might not get the chance to see the about tab getting clicked but you should end up on the about page.

The hard part is figuring out the css path to an element. However once you have it, the `find_by_css()` method looks pretty easy

Answer (score 0):

I like the W3Schools reference for CSS selection parameters: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

As for your code... I recommend breaking this down into a few steps, at least during debug. The call to br.find_by_css('css_string') returns a list of elements. So you can grab that list and check the count.

```
elems = br.find_by_css('div#edit-field-download-files-und-0 a.button.launcher')
if len(elems) == 1:
    elems.first.click()
```

If you don't check the length of the returned list and call '.first' on an empty list, you'll get an exception. If len > 1, you're probably getting things you don't expect.

Each id on a page is unique, and you can daisy-chain searches, so you can use a few different statements to make this happen:

```
  id_elems = br.find_by_id('edit-field-download-files-und-0')
  if id_elems:
      id_elem = id_elems.first
      a_elems = id_elem.find_by_tag("a")
      for e in a_elems:
          if e.has_class("button launcher"):
              print('Found it!')
              e.click()
```

This is, of course, just one of many ways to do this.
Lastly, Splinter is a wrapper around Selenium and other webdrivers. It's possible that, even after you find the element to click, the actual click won't do anything. If this happens, you can also try clicking on the wrapped Selenium object, available as e._element. So you could try e._element.click() if necessary.